# Mui table, best approach for img and for columns with codes

Tags: reactjs, image, material-ui

I'm working with Mui Table in React, and I'm facing 2 situations. I have dynamic tables and some of them have images, which is the best way for rendering that? The field is a URL, different clients would fill it. Right now I'm doing this:

```
{Object.values(row).map((cell) =>
    typeof cell === 'string' &&
    (cell.includes('.jpg') ||
        cell.includes('.png')) ? (
        <TableCell
            align='center'
            key={row.key}
            component='image'
            scope='row'
        >
            <img
                className='table-image'
                src={cell}
            />
        </TableCell>
    ) : (
        <TableCell
            align='center'
            key={row.key}
            component='th'
            scope='row'
        >
            {cell}
        </TableCell>
    )
)}
```

Is there a better way to do this? (I'm not sure either if jpg and png is enough, and if I have to add more options it's going to get worse).

And the other question is about this: I have a field, status, it can be 0 or 1 (unpublished or published), but I don't want to show the number in the table but the word.
I'm doing something awful to achieve this.

```
const { data: partners } = await axiosApiInstance
            .get(API_END_POINT_GET_ALL_PARTNER)
            .catch((err) => {
                setError(true);
                setLoading(false);
                setMessageError(intl.formatMessage(messages.loadPartnersError));
                throw new Error(err);
            });
        partners.forEach(function (partner) {
            if (partner.status === 1) partner.status = 'Published';
            else partner.status = 'Unpublished';
        });
        setData(partners);
```

How can I improve it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective you have two options here.

1. add a regexp that checks image types at your table

```
  Object.values(row).map((cell) =>
    cell.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/) != null ? (   // <-- this is it
      <TableCell
        align='center'
        key={row.key}
        component='image'
        scope='row'
      >
        <img
          className='table-image'
          src={cell}
        />
      </TableCell>
    ) : (
      <TableCell
        align='center'
        key={row.key}
        component='th'
        scope='row'
      >
        {cell}
      </TableCell>
    )
  )
```

2. Actually try if [url is an image](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/javascript+check+if+url+is+image) sending a request to it

```js
function checkImage(url) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.send();
  request.onload = function() {
    status = request.status;
    if (request.status == 200) //if(statusText == OK)
    {
      console.log("image exists");
    } else {
      console.log("image doesn't exist");
    }
  }
}
```